# What are the implications for overriding compareTo?

Tags: java, overriding, compareto

I am aware that if one overrides equals, hashCode should also be overridden.  Are there any similar rules that would apply to overriding compareTo?

This is a Java question.

Comment: Shortly after posting the link, I decided to not be lazy, and actually copy/pasted into an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectations of it can be read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

The part that will be of the most interest to you is probably:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`

Note that it is not *required*, i.e. If two classes are equal according to the `compareTo()`, they don't have to hold `equals()`. This is fine because you can for instance sort people by age, so two people with the same age are considered equal with regards to `Comparator<Person>`, but they obviously don't have to be equal.

However in this particular case you might want to add secondary attributes to comparator if ages are equal (so sorting is always stable and predictable across same-aged people) so after all including the same attributes in `compareTo()` might be a good idea in some cases.

Comment: This is a good point that seems to apply to my case. I measure the utility of objects and sort on utility. (Like the economics definition of utility).  But these objects are not equal.  Utility might be the same by coincidence.

Comment: If the compareTo is used only for sorting, there is no harm, aside from the speed effect, in adding fields to the comparison. In this way, compareTo can be made "consistent" with equals.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) has this cautionary note:

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

Answer (score 0):

I want to just tell you that you should have a particular properties or attribute in objects which you will use to compare two objects of same type.